# How do I run a program locally by clicking an HTML form button?

Tags: c++, html, c, web-applications, cgi

I have a compiled C++ program called "main".
Instead of running the program from a terminal, I would like to click a button on a webpage to run it.
How would I go about doing this?

---

In this example, the browser downloads the program instead of running it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="input" action="main" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Run Program">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by running it _locally_? Running it on the client, or running it on the server?

Comment: Your question is general for all applications, not just for C++ programs.

Comment: @jogojapan There is no server.  I want to open up local html files that provide an interface for running my local programs.

Comment: Usually the web browser protects your machine against html or javascript running local processes.

Comment: You can use ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this without a web server running locally. Starting programs directly by clicking on web pages would lead to serious security problems.

If you are on Windows, and really want to start executables from HTML pages, then consider using an [HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) ([example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/31/how-can-i-start-an-application-from-an-hta.aspx)).

**== EDIT ==**

I just realized that the example I mentioned above shows a way to start a program (notepad.exe) directly from the browser. Save this code as `test.html`, open it in Internet Explorer, and click on the button:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script language="VBScript"> 
    Sub RunProgram 
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "notepad.exe"
    End Sub
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<button onclick="RunProgram">Run Program</button> <p>
</body> 
</html>
```

You will get a warning, but after clicking on "Yes", Notepad will start.

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
        }
>
```

Comment: `ActiveXObject is not defined` in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use this only on your own, do the following. Create a .run file with description of program to be run. It may contain the following values:

```
D:\Programs\MyProgram.exe
Parameter1
Parameter2
Parameter3
```

Then create a simple program (so called runner), which reads a run file, parses it and calls program described in its contents by CreateProcess(). Associate it with .run files. Finally make a link inside your webpage to the .run file - such that your runner will execute its contents. This requires no webserver on your local machine, but this solution is not scalable (eg. your clients won't be able to use it unless registering a runner) and is not really secure. It shouldn't raise any system warnings and do not require embedded scripts in HTML though.

Answer (score 0):

u use phpsh in ur webserver
and u adapt pspsh to run your/ur program directly
instead of returning the terminal prompt
so that http: // webserver / main is the phpsh script 
that runs main program directly
allso u must setup ur paths accordingly 
that apache user has acces to run apps

another option is write the c program as cgi
and have the form been processed by the cgi